# aclaración de bucles for dentro de fragmento de código en python

Tags: python

No entiendo qué hace el código python incluido en esta función. Qué hace el primer bloque de código?

```
def findOut(s):                                                 
    for c in s:                                                    
        if '0' <= c and c <= '9':                                               
            return True                                                     
    return False                                                                                  

d = {"hello": "abc123", "bye": "ab", "day": "ab12", "night": "abc"}                                                           

for element in d.keys():                                                           
    if findOut(d[element]):                                                            
        del d[element]                                                           
print d
```

Comment: @Javocho Las publicaciones que son solamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Deberías editar tu pregunta para añadir más detalles: ¿Qué es lo que hace de forma general ese código? ¿Cuáles son las partes que no logras entender? Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Las partes ya las he puesto es sobretodo la primera función y el problema es ese que no sé que hace ni de forma general

Comment: El código lo tienes que haber sacado de algún sitio o lo tienes que estar ejecutando dentro de un programa. Debes añadir más detalles a la pregunta y poner algo de contexto: ¿qué es lo que se supone que debe hacer? ¿el código falla? ¿da un resultado que no esperas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **for** recorre todas las claves del diccionario **d**, luego, el **if** a continuación evalúa el resultado de la función **findOut**, 
enviando como parámetro el valor de la clave actual (de la iteración del for) del diccionario **d**. En caso de que la función retorne **True**,
la instrucción **del** elimina la clave (junto con su valor) del diccionario.

La función **findOut**, por su parte, recorre los caracteres de la cadena recibida (el valor de cada clave del diccionario), evaluando si es un caracter con valor numérico, 
en caso de serlo, retorna **True**, si no encuentra ningún caracter númerico, retorna **False**.

Al ejecutar el código, éste devuelve un error en tiempo de ejecución: "dictionary changed size during iteration". 
Esto se debe a que dentro del ciclo **for** se está modificando el diccionario en "caliente", o sea, mientras es recorrido.